"Error parsing JSON": how to use `testmempoolaccept` on Windows?
The documentation for bitcoin-cli testmempoolaccept suggests
bitcoin-cli testmempoolaccept '["0100000001abcd..."]'

but that throws Error parsing JSON. I have tried numerous variations of this, but none of them work. How can I use testmempoolaccept on Windows?

The correct format that works for this is bitcoin-cli testmempoolaccept "[\"0100000001abcd...\"]"

The version in the question would work on Linux, it is a difference between how Windows and Linux handle quoting in commands.

Okay, but the question is about Windows, not Linux or Mac OS


That wasn't made clear in the original form of the question. 2. I thought others reading this might not be aware of this OS difference and might find it helpful to know.

